# AWS SMTB compromised. What to do

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ses

We are a small startup currently in prototype phase. We are still in development phase, and are using AWS to host our application and (test) domain. We have hosted our domain on Route 53, and registered that with SES for email services.

I am new to AWS, and have used domination to understand how to set these things up. Now it appears that our account(s) have been compromised/hacked and someone is missing it to send malicious emails.  I am unsure what is the extend of hack, and if the users is only managed to get access to SES and Database credentials. I received an email from SES team, which shows emails have been send through my domain (not by me), but I never created that email on my domain.

Additionally, I have noticed that someone is trying to access my database (from China) and database is always at 100%. Database log says it has blocked IP (which is based in China).

We are using GitHub to store code, and in our code we had credentials for AWS and SMTB servers so I think its possible that someone stoke keys from there (we have taken credential out of GitHub now).

Can someone help me understand what steps do I need to take. I am thinking to shut down this environment and create a new one, but I am unsure how to get hold of my domain and shut down all emails created by spammer on my domain. I am also unclear what is the extend of hack, and if this will come back.

Cam someone please help.

Comment: Why is your database exposed to the Internet?

Comment: I wanted to access database from local app server for build, and that's where we made mistake to open database to public rather than to my own IP.

Comment: This is what VPNs are for. The database can have a private IP and you can VPN into the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You should never store your credentials in github.

In fact, you should use roles instead of credentials stored directly in the code.

So, step by step you should:

- Remove the credentials from github and from your code (done)
- Reset your credentials and do not store them
- Create a role with the policy according to your needs
- Assign that role to your resources.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html#use-roles) you can found more info

Comment: thanks a lot Scouto, much appreciated. What do I do about the email that the "Hacker" has created in my domain. How do I shut that down? I do not have access to that. Secondly, how do I restrict accessing on my database. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dokt know about that. You should have access to ir. Maybe you can talk to aws support. Anyway if you change all your credentials, you should also check allí your iam resources, just in case the hacker made use of it too. Once iam is cleaned Up,  the hacker resources ( even the mail)
 should be  useless